# Alien lizard comes to Earth and becomes a celebrity scientist

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the late 70s or early 80s, there was an alien lizard who comes to Earth. He became a celebrity scientist but then fell from grace.

I have looked for this book or some reference to it for over 20 years. I just stumbled into this website just now. Does anyone know the the title, author, or anything about this book?

Comment: Please try to remember more about the story. How big was the alien lizard? Was it male or female? As a scientist, was it an astronomer, chemist, geologist, physicist, biologist, psychologist? Did it fall from grace for scientific misconduct (plagiarism, falsifying data) or some other reason? Was the story set in the near future? Was it a "first contact" story? The lizard scientist was the first and only space alien humanity had ever seen? Or was it set in a *Star Trek* type future, with lots of communication between humans and aliens? Was the story humorous or serious?

Comment: "Fell from grace" looks like an inconscious echo of *A Case of Conscience* by James Blish, which even ends with an exorcism.

Answer (score 1):

A Case of Conscience by James Blish?

Comment: Could you clarify the reason why you think this is the work OP is looking for? Maybe with a synopsis or relevant excerpts.

Comment: Yes, that could be it, but the OP might not recognize the author and title. Please describe the book, especially the part about the alien on earth.

Comment: *Father Ruiz-Sanchez is a dedicated man--a priest who is also a scientist, and a scientist who is also a human being. He has found no insoluble conflicts in his beliefs or his ethics . . . until he is sent to Lithia. There he comes upon a race of aliens who are admirable in every way except for their total reliance on cold reason; they are incapable of faith or belief.*